# Added Comma when Printing DataTable as String

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

In the following code I am passing through every element of a DataTable and adding it to a string.

```
foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        if (firstpass)
        {
            firstpass = false;
            continue;
        }
        toReturn += column.ColumnName + ",";
    }
    toReturn += ";";
    firstpass = true;
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            if (firstpass)
            {
                firstpass = false;
                continue;
            }
            toReturn += row[column].ToString() + " ";
        }
        firstpass = true;
    }
    return toReturn;
```

Result:

```
"CAD,Celiac,Hypertension,Anticoagulates,Ace Inhibitors,Insulin,;176 25 296 109 73 " + "353 195 18 300 92 73 377 "
```

Can anybody explain why the string returned from the function has the concatenation operator (plus sign)? I am trying to create a comma delimited string but that is causing problems when I interpret the string in a different class.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the result with quotes?

Comment: That algorithm could not have returned the result you posted, specifically the `" + "` part. How did you get this result (debugging, console, etc.)?

Comment: WCF Test Client in Visual Studio

Comment: I just added the picture of it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF test client breaks the string and concatenates it back to display in the "Value" column. See this previous question: [WCF Test Client breaks a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094706/wcf-test-client-breaks-a-string-value-and-then-concatenates-the-2-parts-together)